# Get element id by textcontent in php

Tags: php, text, get, element

I have a php code:

```
$url = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
@$doc->loadHtml($data);

//I want to get element id and all i know is that the element is containg text "Business"

echo $doc->getElementById($id)->textContent;
```

Lets assume, that there is an element on a page a want to keep track of. I don't know the id, just the textcontent at that time. I want to get the id so i could get the textcontent of the same element next week or month, no matter if the text content is changing or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this project:
http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

With this you can use CSS3 selectors like "div:contains('foo')" to find elements containing a text.

Update: An example

The task: Find the elements containing "find me" inside "test.html":

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div>hello</div>
        <div>find me!</div>
        <div>and find me!</div>
        <div>another one</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The PHP-Skript:

```
<?php

include "phpQuery-onefile.php";

phpQuery::newDocumentFileXHTML('test.html');
$domNodes = pq('div:contains("find me")');

foreach($domNodes as $domNode) {
    /** @var DOMNode */
    echo $domNode->textContent . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The result of running it:

```
php test.php
find me!
and find me!
```

Comment: I'm trying to get somewhere with PHP query, but I canot get it done.. Can you help me wih it?

Comment: It didn't work this way but I've changed it to phpQuery::newDocumentHTML(
file_get_contents('Page3.html')
); and now is it OK. THANK YOU!